# Asp .Net Core Activate Background Task after Logic

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm building a delivery application where delivery user can generate a delivery list which has date when is created and date to finish the user selects.

Now I want to activate a background task that that executes a timer based on the start and end date of the delivery list and after timer finishes it executes a database call to update status.

I have looked into
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2

But I have no idea how to call this worker from a page method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeliveryAsync()
{
    await _context.Deliveries.Add(Delivery);

    // Call task       

    return Page();
}
```

Comment: If you await this task, it wont return 200 OK to the user until done. If you dont, you wont have a reference to the timer. Have you considered creating a singleton service which maintains all the active timers? Alternatively, without timers I suppose you could just keep them in DB and iterate the active deliveries infinitely, updating their status when appropriate.

Comment: I think your title is slightly misleading since you want this task to be part of the logic. but for a schedular that runs after logic has completed I have used hangfire and it met my needs. https://www.hangfire.io/ . (I'm not affiliated with Hangfire). another idea for something like this could be seperating this logic into a lambda function or azure function.

Comment: i will look into both approaches as i only need a way to start a task after x time. It doesn't really need to be part of logic though, there has to be a way to start the task using some trigger on the logic

Comment: I believe the [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.8) referenced by your link can do just that.

Comment: You don't need to call anything. Just implement a timer based hosted service, like the example provided in the documentation you linked to. Each time the timer triggers on the service, query the database for matching deliveries based on your specs and then then modify the status on those and save. Simply adding the delivery to the database, then, is enough to "schedule" it.

Comment: Yes but i thought i could trigger it when it was created instead of making a task that is constantly working to save CPU usage